# How to convert IntelliJ key mappings to VSCode keybindings?

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

I'm very used to, and have extensively customized, my IntelliJ key mappings. They differ a lot from the default ones, and so neither of the existing VSCode plugins ([1](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings), [2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=isudox.vscode-jetbrains-keybindings)) does the job for me.

Apart from manually setting the bindings in VSCode, is there a way to port my existing mappings to VSCode?